# Trouble enabling submit button on radio button select using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, backbone.js, onclick, radio-button

I have a form and I want to keep submit button disabled until required radio buttons are selected.Now I want that if user checks Radio button Red then submit is enabled but if user checks Green then it should check if anyone of alpha or beta are selected or no, if selected then enable submit button otherwise keep it disabled until user checks any of them. Here is my template and jquery code.

```
<div class="type1">
     <div id="Red">
      <input type="radio" class="colorType red" name="colorType" value="Red">Red
     </div>
     <div id="Green">
      <input type="radio" class="colortype green" name="colorType" value="Green">Green
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="type2">
     <input type="radio" class="frequency" name="frequency" value="alpha">Alpha
     <input type="radio" class="frequency" name="frequency" value="beta">Beta
    </div>
    <span class="float-right">
    <button class="button-save" disabled>Save &#38; Close</button>
</span>
```

**My javascript code is**

```
events : {
  'change .colorType': 'removeDisable'
},
  removeDisable : function(){
    if ($('.red').is(':checked')) {
      $(".button-savel").attr("disabled", false);
    } else if ($('.green').is(':checked')) {
      if ($('.frequency').is(':checked')) {
        $(".button-save").attr("disabled", false);
      }else {
        $(".button-save").attr("disabled", true);
      }

    } else {
      return false;
    }
  },
```

everything works fine but when I click on green and select alpha or beta then button does not get enabled. otherwise if i click on red button gets enabled.
My javascript is for backbone js.

Comment: Use `prop` instead of `attr` and `is` http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: You shouldn't use global selectors like this in backbone view...

Comment: if ($('.frequency:checked').length) this should be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out the problem, I need another on change event after clicking green. Creating an on change event on frequency and then calling that function when I click green solved the issue.

```
events : {
'change .colorType': 'removeDisable',
'change .frequency': 'frequencyChange'
},
frequencyChange : function(){
if ($('.frequency').is(':checked')) {
    $(".button-save").attr("disabled", false);
  }else {
    $(".button-save").attr("disabled", true);
  }
},
removeDisable : function(){
if ($('.red').is(':checked')) {
  $(".button-savel").attr("disabled", false);
} else if ($('.green').is(':checked')) {
    $(".button-save").attr("disabled", true);
this.frequencyChange();
} else {
  return false;
}
},
```

This solved the problem. Good thing I was able to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing that the `.is()` check is not succeeding because there are two items to check and both cannot be checked at the same time -- maybe try checking each individually with an 'or' comparison?

```
if ($($('.frequency')[0]).is(':checked') || $($('.frequency')[1]).is(':checked')) {
```

good luck!

Comment: Tried that, same issue :(

Comment: `$('.frequency')[0]` is supposed to be `$($('.frequency')[0])`, since you are trying to invoke `is` method, which is only implemented for jQuery objects.

Comment: updated answer according to @Sushanth--'s comment -- good call since the array access of a jquery object returns DOM elements, not jQuery objects